# what does linker script notation "ROM_NOCOPY“ means?

Tags: linker-scripts, nxp-microcontroller

I can't found the specific definition or any explanation about the linker notation "ROM_NOCOPY" shows in the following ld files snippets,

```
MEMORY
{
  CM7_CORE_DTCM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000 , LENGTH = 0x00010000 /* 64 KiB */
  INTVEC_CORE0_BLOCK : ORIGIN = 0x340C0000 , LENGTH = 0x00000400 /* 1024 Byte */
  INTVEC_CORE1_BLOCK : ORIGIN = 0x340C0400 , LENGTH = 0x00000400 /* 1024 Byte */
  INTVEC_CORE2_BLOCK : ORIGIN = 0x340C0800 , LENGTH = 0x00000400 /* 1024 Byte */
  StartUp_volatile_RAM : ORIGIN = 0x340C0C00 , LENGTH = 0x00003400 /* 13 KiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_CODE : ORIGIN = 0x340C4000 , LENGTH = 0x0047C000 /* 4 MiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_GLOBAL_QM : ORIGIN = 0x34540000 , LENGTH = 0x000ADC00 /* 695 KiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_GLOBAL_SAF : ORIGIN = 0x345EDC00 , LENGTH = 0x00002000 /* 8 KiB */
  HSE_Section : ORIGIN = 0x345EFC00 , LENGTH = 0x00000400 /* 1024 Byte */
  INTERNAL_RAM_GLOBAL_ASILC : ORIGIN = 0x345F0000 , LENGTH = 0x00010000 /* 64 KiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_CORE0_EA_ASILC : ORIGIN = 0x34600000 , LENGTH = 0x000A0000 /* 640 KiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_CORE0_EA_QM : ORIGIN = 0x346A0000 , LENGTH = 0x00010000 /* 64 KiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_CORE1_EA_ASILC : ORIGIN = 0x346B0000 , LENGTH = 0x00010000 /* 64 KiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_CORE1_EA_QM : ORIGIN = 0x346C0000 , LENGTH = 0x00020000 /* 128 KiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_CORE2_EA_ASILC : ORIGIN = 0x346E0000 , LENGTH = 0x00008000 /* 32 KiB */
  INTERNAL_RAM_CORE2_EA_QM : ORIGIN = 0x346E8000 , LENGTH = 0x00018000 /* 96 KiB */
  XCP_CAL_RAM_QM : ORIGIN = 0x34700004 , LENGTH = 0x000DFFFC /* 896 KiB */
  XCP_CAL_RAM_ASILC : ORIGIN = 0x347E0000 , LENGTH = 0x0001C000 /* 112 KiB */
  LLCE_CAN_SHAREDMEMORY : ORIGIN = 0x43800000 , LENGTH = 0x0003D000 /* 244 KiB */
  LLCE_LIN_SHAREDMEMORY : ORIGIN = 0x4383D000 , LENGTH = 0x00003000 /* 12 KiB */
  LLCE_BOOT_END : ORIGIN = 0x43840000 , LENGTH = 0x00000050 /* 80 Byte */
  m_hse_shared_mem_start_mu0: ORIGIN = 0x22C00000, LENGTH = 0x1000
  m_hse_shared_mem_start_mu1: ORIGIN = 0x22C01000, LENGTH = 0x1000
  m_hse_shared_mem_start_mu2: ORIGIN = 0x22C02000, LENGTH = 0x1000
  m_hse_shared_mem_start_mu3: ORIGIN = 0x22C03000, LENGTH = 0x1000
  Standby_sCheck_RAM (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x24007F00 , LENGTH = 0x00000100 /* 256 Byte */
  DDR_RAM_0 : ORIGIN = 0x60200000 , LENGTH = 0x000E0000 /* 896 KiB */
}
SECTIONS
{
  /* snippets*/
  .data_core2_ea_QM_ROM ROM_NOCOPY(.data_core2_ea_QM) :> INTERNAL_RAM_CORE2_EA_QM
  _data_core2_ea_QM_ROM_START = ADDR(.data_core2_ea_QM_ROM);
  _data_core2_ea_QM_ROM_LIMIT = ADDR(.data_core2_ea_QM_ROM) + SIZEOF(.data_core2_ea_QM_ROM);

  .data_core2_ea_QM ALIGN(4) :
  {
    _data_core2_ea_QM_START = .;
    *(.data_core2_ea_QM)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _data_core2_ea_QM_END = . - 1;
    _data_core2_ea_QM_LIMIT = .;
  } > INTERNAL_RAM_CORE2_EA_QM
/* snippets*/
}
```

In my humbled experience, I guess here the liker script was try to put the input section ".data_core2_ea_QM" into the output section both "data_core2_ea_QM_ROM" and "data_core2_ea_QM" in sequence, but don't know what this was for, and what the ROM_COPY notation stands for ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use GreenHills compiler. The section attribute of **ROM_NOCOPY** tells the linker not to add this section into the run-time copy table. That is, the startup code will not copy the content from `.data_core2_ea_QM_ROM` to `.data_core2_ea_QM` in your case. Instead, you need to handle the section copy by yourself.

Another thing is which memory region `.data_core2_ea_QM_ROM` goes. Let's denote `.data_core2_ea_QM_ROM` and `.data_core2_ea_QM` as the new section and the existing section respectively. You should not specify any contents and attributes for the new section as it inherits them from the existing section. Then `.data_core2_ea_QM_ROM` should be put into a ROM memory block instead of `INTERNAL_RAM_CORE2_EA_QM` same as the existing section of `.data_core2_ea_QM`. There is no point in keeping two same copies on the same memory block at least IMO.

Comment: you means GreenHills compiler generate run-time copy table according section attribute of ROM_COPY , so is there exists a copy table format conventions which obeyed by  both compiler vendor and chip vendor, if the answer is yes, where can i found those conventions (by websites or books)

Comment: ps. thanks for your reply, according to your answers, i found some copy table relevant stuffs in MULTI: Building Applications for Embedded ARM v2020.1 user-manual